# How to count the result of this scenarios?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm now trying to make a corresponding list of the result after the user choose some conditions.

What I write in controller:

```
$temp="SELECT
            v_realestates.house_Id,
            v_realestates.unit_Price,   
            w_builds.tran_Area,
            x_lands.Ltran_TotArea,
            y_parkinglots.parking_Price
        FROM
            w_builds
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            x_lands ON x_lands.house_Id = w_builds.house_Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            v_realestates ON v_realestates.house_Id = w_builds.house_Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            y_parkinglots ON y_parkinglots.house_Id = w_builds.house_Id
        WHERE
            x_lands.house_Id = w_builds.house_Id = v_realestates.house_Id = y_parkinglots.house_Id ";

        if (@$_GET['city']!="") {
            $temp=$temp." and v_realestates.the_Location like '%".$_GET['city']."%'";
        }
        if (@$_GET['district']!="") {
            $temp=$temp." and v_realestates.the_Location like'%".$_GET['district']."%'";
        }

        if (@$_GET['unit_Price']!="") {
            if(@$_GET['unit_Price']=="un1"){
                $temp=$temp." and v_realestates.unit_Price between 0 and 200000";
            }
            else if(@$_GET['unit_Price']=="un2"){
                $temp=$temp." and v_realestates.unit_Price between 200001 and 400000";
            }
            else if(@$_GET['unit_Price']=="un3"){
                $temp=$temp." and v_realestates.unit_Price between 400001 and 600000";
            }
        }
        if (@$_GET['tot_Price']!="") {
            if(@$_GET['tot_Price']=="to1"){
                $temp=$temp." and v_realestates.tot_Price < 9000000";
            }
            else if(@$_GET['tot_Price']=="to2"){
                $temp=$temp." and v_realestates.tot_Price between 9000000 and 15000000";
            }
            else if(@$_GET['tot_Price']=="to3"){
                $temp=$temp." and v_realestates.tot_Price between 15000001 and 25000000";
            }
        }

        $query = DB::select($temp);
        $theNum = DB::select('SELECT COUNT(house_Id) AS houseNum FROM v_realestates');
        $theunPrice = DB::SELECT('SELECT ROUND(AVG(unit_Price),-4) AS avgunPrice FROM v_realestates');
        $thetotPrice = DB::SELECT('SELECT ROUND(AVG(tot_Price),-4) AS avgtotPrice FROM v_realestates');

    }
    $page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage("page");
    $perPage = 10;
    $offset = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;
    $X_land= new LengthAwarePaginator(array_slice($query, $offset, $perPage, true), count($query), $perPage, $page, ['path' =>  Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]);


    return \View::make('holyfive.generalsearch', compact('X_land','theNum','theunPrice','thetotPrice'));
```

What I have in blade:

```
<div class="searchresult2">
    <ul>
        @foreach($theNum as $Num)
          <li id="areatitle">[ Total row<span class="numberofresult">{{ $Num->houseNum }}</span> ]</li>
        @endforeach
        @foreach($theunPrice as $unPrice)
          <li>The unit price <br><span class="resultprice">{{ $unPrice->avgunPrice/10000 }}</span></li>
        @endforeach
        @foreach($thetotPrice as $totPrice)
           <li>The total price <br><span class="resultprice">{{ $totPrice->avgtotPrice/10000 }}</span></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

I know the above one can get total number of `house_Id` and calculate `unit_Price` in database. I am trying to change this one into an interactive one  according to what user choose from drop-down list, what should I do to calculate `theNum` `theunPrice`  `thetotPrice`.

Thanks for giving me any suggestions.